# Which one is better to support multilingual environment on linux virtual terminal?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, ibus, internationalization, input-method

I want to make multilingual console/terminal environment on Ubuntu12.04 LTS.
In detail, I'm going to input and display CJK(Chinese, Japanese, Korean) on virtual console/terminal.
After some of web surfing I found there were several solutions.

- fbterm + ucimf
- ucimf + ibus
- jfbterm

Which one is best of them in this case?